# How do you access NSManagedObjects between blocks?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

Like the title says how does one go about accessing an NSManagedObject that has been created in one block and then needs to be accessed in the other. I have the following implementation and was wondering if it's correct.

```
__block Person *newPerson;

@weakify(self);
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    newPerson = [Person MR_createInContext:localContext];
    newPerson.name = @"Bob";

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    @strongify(self);
    // Called on main thread

    PersonViewController *personVC = [[PersonViewController alloc] initWithPerson:newPerson];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:personVC animated:YES];

}];
```

Am I correct in not needing to access newPerson from a localContext in the completion handler because it'll be executed on the main thread?

**EDIT**

It looks like the following is the proposed way:

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *newPersonObjectID;

@weakify(self);
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    Person *newPerson = [Person MR_createInContext:localContext];
    newPerson.name = @"Bob";
    newPersonObjectID = newPerson.objectID;

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    @strongify(self);
    // Called on main thread

    Person *savedPerson = [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] objectWithID:newPersonObjectID];

    PersonViewController *personVC = [[PersonViewController alloc] initWithPerson:savedPerson];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:personVC animated:YES];

}];
```

**Solution**

This answer and comments lead to the following solution.
A TemporaryID is being assigned to the object whilst it's being saved and therefore when trying to fetch the object with the TempID an exception occurs.

Rather than creating a whole new fetch request what can be done is asking the context to obtain the permanent IDs early and than acquiring the permanent ID of the object. For example:

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *newPersonObjectID;

@weakify(self);
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    Person *newPerson = [Person MR_createInContext:localContext];
    newPerson.name = @"Bob";

    [localContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[newPerson] error:NULL];

    newPersonObjectID = newPerson.objectID;

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    @strongify(self);
    // Called on main thread

    Person *savedPerson = [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] objectWithID:newPersonObjectID];

    PersonViewController *personVC = [[PersonViewController alloc] initWithPerson:savedPerson];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:personVC animated:YES];

}];
```

Comment: Did we answer the question you have?  You can edit your question if there anything specific the community can still assist you with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly pass managed objects between contexts.  Each `NSManagedObject` can only be accessed by its own context.

You'll need to pass its `objectID` to the completion block, then have the main context fetch the object by calling one of the following methods:

```
-(NSManagedObject *)objectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
```

This will create a fault to an object with the specified objectID, whether or not it actually exists in the store. If it doesn't exist, anything that fires the fault will fail with an exception.

```
-(NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
                                   error:(NSError **)error
```

This will fetch the object from the store that has that ID, or return nil if it doesn't exist.  Unlike `objectWithID`, the object won't be faulted; all its attributes will have been retrieved.

In either case, your local context must have saved the `Person` object to the store for the main context to be able to fetch it.

More details about `objectID` can be found in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001803-SW1)

**Edit by User Asking Question**

This answer and comments lead to the correct solution.
A TemporaryID is being assigned to the object whilst it's being saved and therefore when trying to fetch the object with the TempID an exception occurs.

Rather than creating a whole new fetch request what can be done is asking the context to obtain the permanent IDs early and than acquiring the permanent ID of the object. For example:

```
__block NSManagedObjectID *newPersonObjectID;

@weakify(self);
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

    Person *newPerson = [Person MR_createInContext:localContext];
    newPerson.name = @"Bob";

    [localContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[newPerson] error:NULL];

    newPersonObjectID = newPerson.objectID;

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    @strongify(self);
    // Called on main thread

    Person *savedPerson = [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] objectWithID:newPersonObjectID];

    PersonViewController *personVC = [[PersonViewController alloc] initWithPerson:savedPerson];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:personVC animated:YES];

}];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I've updated the code. Could you advise if this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  The only thing I'd add is that before an object is saved, it has a temporary objectID.  After it is saved, it is given a permanent objectID.  I don't use MagicalRecord, so I don't know if you'll have to first obtain the permanent ID before trying to get the managed object in the completion block.  I think objectWithID might want a permanent ID, but existingObjectWithID might work with a temporary ID.

Comment: Ahhhh that's it! I didn't realise that it's a TempID in the child context, thank you! In the completion block using objectWithID was causing an exception because obviously I had the TempID. I'll see if existingObjectWithID can return an object from a TempID, if not it looks like I may need to fetch the object.

Comment: Alright so it didn't but I found this fantastic answer where you can force the permanent id to be created within the save block.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14115769/4698501

Thank you for your help in getting me to this point! I'll try to edit your answer so it's more relevant to what I've discovered and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should access the objectID outside of your block (on the main thread, for example) and then use it within your block. Something like:

```
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = appDelegate.myObject.objectId;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // use objectID here.
}
```